# Python, Flask ошибка: AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'dumps'

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, flask, jinja2

День добрый подскажите в чём проблема до сегодняшнего дня всё работало, сегодня открыл проект и вижу следующее, работаю в среде пайчарм

```
E:\python\app\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:/python/app/app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python/app/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask, render_template
  File "E:\python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
  File "E:\python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "E:\python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 15, in <module>
    from jinja2 import nodes
  File "E:\python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\nodes.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2.utils import Markup
  File "E:\python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\utils.py", line 41, in <module>
    _slash_escape = '\\/' not in json.dumps('/')
AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'dumps'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Странная ошибка: возникает в внутрях сторонней библиотеки jinja2, ругается на отсутствие в стандартном модуле json, стандартного метода dumps. Судя по коду из того места https://github.com/pallets/jinja/blob/master/jinja2/utils.py#L41 проблем не должно быть. У вас не было ли каких-либо манипуляций с модулем json? :) Попробуйте выполнить `import json` и `print(json.dumps)` должно вывести `<function dumps at ...`

Comment: Похоже вы создали свой собственный “json.py”, который затенил стандартный модуль

Comment: Как тогда всё удалить и установить заново?

Comment: @MaxU на Тостере в такой же вопросе он утверждает, что файла json.py у него в проекте нет.

Comment: Дак вот и фиг что его нет, в проекте его точно нет. Где он может ещё быть, сам я его точно не создавал

Comment: @Владимир, попробуйте переименовать свои директорию и имя файла, чтобы они не назывались “app” и “app.py”

Answer (score 0):

В итоге решил удалить python и всё его окружение с компа, перезагрузил и заново поставил в и тоге заработало но с ошибками. Вот они, что ему опять не так)))

```
E:\python\app\venv\Scripts\python.exe E:/python/app/app.py
```

Error processing line 1 of E:\python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\json_extensions-0.2.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "", line 580, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of E:\python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\json_extensions-0.2.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "", line 580, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
Error processing line 1 of E:\python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\json_extensions-0.2.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "", line 580, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of E:\python\app\venv\lib\site-packages\json_extensions-0.2.1-py3.7-nspkg.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site.py", line 168, in addpackage
      exec(line)
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "", line 580, in module_from_spec
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 279-512-791
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2019 11:21:40] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Mar/2019 11:21:47] "GET /python HTTP/1.1" 200 -